# Python inherited base class variables

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

So I have `Base` class with two Child classes. The idea was that I would have a model containing all data which I could plug into one of the child classes. Then call a method to set the headers on each of the child classes and then duplicate the data from the `Model` to the `Child` class instance. However I found out that after calling the `add_header` method on the first class instance (a in this case) b also got the header. Which kinda confused me because I thought that initiated classes do not affect one another. My question is why is this the case and can it possibly be avoided?

```
class Base(object):
    __model__ = None
    headers = ['base_header','base_header2']

    def add_header(self, *args):
        for h in args:
            self.headers.append(h)

    def set_header_values(self):
        for h in self.headers:
            setattr(self, h, getattr(self.__model__, h))


class ChildOne(Base):
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.__model__ = model


class ChildTwo(Base):
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.__model__ = model


class Model(object):
    foo = 'bar'

m = Model()
a = ChildOne(m)
b = ChildTwo(m)
a.add_header('tralala')
print b.headers // Output ['base_header','base_header2','tralala']
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are trying to do, why is `headers` not an instance variable in the first place?

Comment: @timgeb Headers contains some 'base' header which are present in both models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"after calling the add_header method on the first class instance (a in this case) b also got the header"
Because both instances share same variable headers.
headers should be **instance** rather than a **class** variable

```
class Base(object):
    __model__ = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.headers = []

    def add_header(self, *args):
        for h in args:
            self.headers.append(h)

    def set_header_values(self):
        for h in self.headers:
            setattr(self, h, getattr(self.__model__, h))


class ChildOne(Base):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(ChildOne, self).__init__()
        self.__model__ = model


class ChildTwo(Base):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(ChildTwo, self).__init__()
        self.__model__ = model


class Model(object):
    foo = 'bar'

m = Model()
a = ChildOne(m)
b = ChildTwo(m)
a.add_header('tralala')
print a.headers
print b.headers
```

**Output**

['tralala']

[]

**Additional note**

Python class and instance variables cause confusions. Consider the following example:

```
class A:
    l =[] 

class B:
    l =[]

x = A()
y = A()
x.l.append(1)
print 'class A ', A.l, x.l, y.l

x = B()
y = B()
x.l = [1]
print 'class B ', B.l, x.l, y.l
```

**Output**

```
class A  [1] [1] [1]
class B  [] [1] []
```

Both examples use very similar looking access to data member 'l' however first example modifies the already existing class variable while second example creates a new instance variable.

In your example should you had an assignment `self.headers = [...]` instead of `self.append(...)` your output would be different.

*Beside, `__model__` attribute in your question has nothing to do with the problem.*